# Почему QualitySettings ругается на names? И на GetQualityLevel?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему QualitySettings ругается на names? И на GetQualityLevel?

Assets/Scripts/GraphicSettings.cs(16,45): error CS0117: `QualitySettings' does not contain a definition for`names'

Assets/Scripts/GraphicSettings.cs(17,42): error CS0117: `QualitySettings' does not contain a definition for`GetQualityLevel'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;



public class GraphicSettings : MonoBehaviour {

    public Dropdown dropDown;

    void Start () {

        dropDown.ClearOptions();
        dropDown.AddOptions(QualitySettings.names.ToList());
        dropDown.value = QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel();
    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в том же пространстве имён находится ещё один класс QualitySettings. Оно цепляется к нему, видит, что там таких методов и полей нет и выдаёт вам соответствующую ошибку.

Обратитесь к нужному вам явным образом: UnityEngine.QualitySettings, либо переименуйте ваш класс.

Comment: какой именно класс? GraficSettings?

Comment: Cпасибо большое

Comment: @Shelby, класс с именем QualitySettings. Если вопрос решён - отметьте ответ верным. Это его закроет.